# Start a perl script in a console from bash

Tags: perl, bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script that is a watchdog for a perl script. It checks to see if the perl script is running if it isn't I want it to start it in a console. To run the perl script directly from a console I use

```
 usr/bin/xterm -e perl /path/to/file/script.pl
```

How would I get this to launch within a bash script?

Comment: Do you mean `/usr/bin/xterm`?  If so, what happens when you add just this exact line to your Bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the script is not already running:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  /usr/bin/xterm -e perl /path/to/file/script.pl
done
```